# Find limit of ${(2x-14)}^{1/6}$ as $x$ approaches $7$

Tags: limits

Find $\lim\limits_{x \to 7} {(2x-14)}^{1/6}$

My answer is $0^{1/6}$ which I suppose must be equal to $0$.

But the solution says limit does not exist.

Comment: As $x \to 7^-,$ $2x-14 \to 0^-,$ for which real valued sixth root doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

As the function is only defined for arguments $\ge7$,

$$\lim_{x\to7}(2x-14)^{1/6}=\lim_{x\to7^+}(2x-14)^{1/6}=0.$$

The fact that $\lim_{x\to7^-}(2x-14)^{1/6}$ is not defined is irrelevant, as the arguments $<7$ do not belong to the domain of definition.